# Django signals not fired when saving from admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-oscar

I have configured some django signals on the `pre_delete`, `post_save` and `pre_delete` receivers for some models which are stored in a `signals.py` file in the same package as the models.

Saving from an API call or directly in the terminal triggers the signals but when saving from the Admin dashboard they are not fired.
I have imported the signals in the `ready()` method of the `AppConfig` which changes nothing.

Any help on this issue?

PS: Using django-oscar if that helps.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save, pre_delete

from django.dispatch import receiver

from oscar.core.loading import get_model

MyModel = get_model('mypackage', 'MyModel')

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def do_stuff(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    update_stuff()
```

Comment: Pls post your model and related code to help

Comment: Added a snippet to show the organisation, `update_stuff()` never gets called when saving from the admin

Comment: What do you mean by "admin dashboard" - is that the Django admin or the Oscar dashboard? If Oscar dashboard then how have you made your model editable through the dashboard?

Comment: It's the default django admin interface, not the oscar dashboard.
The models are registered using the default `admin.ModelAdmin` from django.

Comment: Does the ready() method of your AppConfig get used by the Django Admin app? I assume it doesn't?

Comment: I don't suppose it does, just trying all possible options.
Is there a way to explicitly load the signals in the Django Admin App?

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem. My Problem was to upload the image to some other destination once the model is saved though admin. Solved it by implementing Admin class on admin.py
e.g if you have a model namely Shop then in your admin.py would be like

```
@admin.register(Shop)
class ShopAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.instance
        instance.save()
        image_path = instance.banner_image.path
        move_image(image_path)
```